# Retornar o Array com valor verde. Quando o botão for clicado, retorne o valor imediatamente acima do botão

Tags: javascript, html

Retorne um array com cada valor verde no carregamento da página (mostrar no console). Quando o botão for clicado, retorne o valor imediatamente acima do botão.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Teste 002</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.slim.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
          (function (win, doc) {
            var f = doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            var j = doc.createElement("script");
            j.async = true;
            j.src = './tagueamento.js';
            f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
          })(window, document);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>
        Retorne um array com cada valor verde no carregamento da página (mostrar no console). Quando o botão for clicado,
        retorne o valor imediatamente acima do botão.
    </h1>
    <style>
        #valores span {
            background: green;
        }
        span{
            color: white;
        }
        #valores span, #botoes a {
            width: 125px;
            margin: 1em;
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #botoes {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="valores">
        <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
    </div>
    <div id="botoes">
        <a>1</a>
        <a>2</a>
        <a>3</a>
        <a>4</a>
        <a>5</a>
    </div>
    <script>
      $('#valores').find('span').each(function () {
        $(this).text('cxxx-xxbx-xaxx'.replace(/x/g, function () {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString(10);
        }))
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use o modo tela cheia**

```js
(function(win, doc) {
  var f = doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  var j = doc.createElement("script");
  j.async = true;
  j.src = './tagueamento.js';
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document);


(() => {
  const arrayValores = [];
  document.querySelectorAll("#valores span").forEach((span, index) => {
    let cod = ('cxxx-xxbx-xaxx').replace(/x/g, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString(10));
    arrayValores.push(cod);
    span.innerHTML = arrayValores[index];
    document.querySelectorAll("#botoes a")[index].onclick = e => console.log(arrayValores[index]);
  });
  console.log(arrayValores);
})();
```

```css
#valores span {
  background: green;
}

span {
  color: white;
}

#valores span,
#botoes a {
  width: 125px;
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#botoes {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Teste 002</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>
    Retorne um array com cada valor verde no carregamento da página (mostrar no console). Quando o botão for clicado, retorne o valor imediatamente acima do botão.
  </h1>

  <div id="valores">
    <span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span>
  </div>
  <div id="botoes">
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
    <a>5</a>
  </div>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Isso pode funcionar nesse caso:

```
(() => {
    const arrayValores = [];
    document.querySelectorAll("#valores span").forEach((span, index) => {
        let cod = ('cxxx-xxbx-xaxx').replace(/x/g, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString(10));
        arrayValores.push(cod);
        span.innerHTML = arrayValores[index];
        document.querySelectorAll("#botoes a")[index].onclick = e => console.log(arrayValores[index]);
    });
    console.log(arrayValores);
})();
```

Comment: Ilustre, boa tarde! Não consegui efeito no projeto. Pode ser mais especifico.

Comment: Eu substitui o seu script no final da pagina e coloquei dentro dessa nova função

Comment: Ela cria um array de valores e começa a percorrer os span's na pagina, feito isso ela gera o codigo ('cxxx-xxbx-xaxx') e coloca no html e ao mesmo tempo adiciona o evento ao botão

Comment: Você recebe algum erro no console? Executei aqui com o pagina que postou e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: A tela fica estática, não  está retornando um array com cada valor verde no carregamento da página (mostrar no console). Quando o botão for clicado, retorne o valor imediatamente acima do botão.

Comment: Executando aqui no site funciona normalmente?

Comment: Aqui no site funciona!

Comment: Executa o codigo que postei no console no browser, vê se surte efeito, por alguma razão parece que a funcão não esta se auto invocando no carregamento da pagina